# Combine values of two rows into single row using SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

```
ID  QuestionNo  AnswerPercent
1    15          10  
1    16          10  
1    17          20
1    18          25
2    15          30
2    16          0
2    17          15
2    18          25
```

Output

```
ID  QuestionNo  AnswerPercent
1    15          10  
1    16          30  
1    17          20
1    18          25
2    15          30
2    16          15
2    17          15
2    18          25
```

For each id the answer percent for questions 16 and 17 need to be merged into 16. Chances are for some ids there may not be any 16 or 17 question numbers.

Can anyone help me out in this. Thanks!.

Comment: Questions asking for code **must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved**. Tell us what you've tried to do, why it didn't work, and how it should work. See also: [Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist)

Comment: What do you mean by merging? Add them together? Keep one of the two values? If so, which of duplicates would you keep and why?

Comment: What I meant was adding just the Answer percent for QuestionNo - 16 with answerPercent of 17 for the same ID.

Comment: Are you trying to merge the values in the table? ie `UPDATE`, or just `SELECT` the results?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this is what you're after, an `UPDATE` with a `JOIN` to a subquery:

```
UPDATE A
SET A.AnswerPercent = B.AnswerPercent
FROM YourTable A
JOIN (SELECT ID, SUM(AnswerPercent)'AnswerPercent'
      FROM YourTable
      WHERE QuestionNo IN ('16','17')
      GROUP BY ID
     )B
ON A.ID = B.ID
WHERE A.QuestionNo = '16'
```

Demo: [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/226a3e/1/0)

Comment: I was trying to UPDATE. Thank you very much for the demo.

Answer (score 1):

try adding the table twice...
 table aliased as `a` has all rows except the ones for question 17, and
 table aliased as `b` has the rows for question 17

```
Select a.Id, a.QuestionNo,
   a.AnswerPercent + 
       case A.QuestionNo When 16 
       then coalesce(b.AnswerPercent, 0) End 
       else 0 End AnswerPercent
From table a 
   left Join table b 
     on a.id = b.Id 
       And a.QuestionNo != 17
       And b.QuestionNo = 17
```

if all you want is to update the existing table, then you need an update and a delete.

```
update a set 
    AnswerPercent = a.AnswerPercent + 
      IsNull(b.AnswerPercent, 0)
from table a 
   left Join table b  
     on a.id = b.Id 
       And a.QuestionNo = 16
       And b.QuestionNo = 17

 --and then ... 

 delete table where QuestionNo = 17
```

Answer (score 0):

```
with aaa as(
select sum(AnswerPercent) as AnswerPercent,ID
from Table
where QuestionNo in (16,17)
group by ID)

select * from Table where QuestionNo <> 16
union
select ID, 16, sum
from aaa
order by ID,AnswerPercent
```